# What are the steps to connect my Azure Linux VM to a clearDB MySQL DB?

Tags: codeigniter, azure, centos, firewall

Our organization is currently transitioning to a Linux VM in Windows Azure, that serves various websites for our clients. As recommended in the Azure documentation, we've set up a mysql DB on ClearDB which we're hoping will hold the data for the aforementioned web sites.

Trouble is, that I cannot get our site code to communicate with clearDB at all.

---

**EDIT**

Connecting from MYSQL command line on the virtual machine DOES work, and we're able to browse the database using the same credentials that the site uses, but php still cannot access the data.

---

We're running php / codeigniter as the backend for the site, and all works fine in my local copy of the site, but always fails the DB connection when deployed to azure.

I've installed tcptraceroute on the azure VM and am able to successfully ping the clearDB machine on port 3306, so it's definitely visible to the VM, but not to the site for some reason.

below is my database configuration for codeigniter which functions just fine running under apache on my local machine.

```
$active_group = "live";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['live']['hostname'] = "eu-cdbr-azure-north-a.cloudapp.net"; 
$db['live']['username'] = "<<USER>>"; 
$db['live']['password'] = "<<PASSWORD>>"; 


$db['live']['database'] = "<<DB NAME>>";
$db['live']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['live']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['live']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['live']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['live']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['live']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['live']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['live']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['live']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['live']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['live']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Does anyone know, firstly if it's even possible to use clearDB for data services from an Azure VM ( note NOT an Azure Website - which I know is possible ), and secondly, how on earth you set it up?

thanks!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything obvious that would prevent it from working. Try setting `$db['live']['port'] = 3306;` I've seen that mess up db connections before.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help. I also cannot connect phpymyadmin to clearDB from the Azure VM despite the same settings working on my local PC :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - our apache configuration was incorrect, setting:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

solved the issue